# Implement get/set methods for Identity User custom property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using Identity and have extended the base IdentityUser with three custom properties.  Using .netCore 3.1.1 and identity 4

```
namespace FleetLogix.Intranet.Identity
{
    // Add profile data for application users by adding properties to the ApplicationUser class
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
    {
        [MaxLength(50)]
        [PersonalData]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(50)]
        [PersonalData]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(5)]
        public string OrgCode { get; set; }

        public ApplicationUser() : base()
        {

        }


    }
}
```

These were happily created in the `[AspNetUsers]` table.  4 initial users have been created, with all additional properties filled.

I have also created some extensions that let me get the values of these properties.  FirstName -> GivenName, LastName -> Surname and OrgCode is a CustomClaimTypes.OrgCode

```
namespace FleetLogix.Intranet.Identity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Extends the <see cref="System.Security.Principal.IIdentity" /> object to add accessors for our custom properties.
    /// </summary>
    public static class IdentityExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the value of the custom user property FirstName
        /// </summary>
        /// <example>
        /// User.Identity.GetFirstName()
        /// </example>
        /// <param name="identity">Usually the Identity of the current logged in User</param>
        /// <returns><see langword="string"/> containing value of LastName or an empty string</returns>
        public static string GetFirstName(this IIdentity identity)
        {
            ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            Claim claim = claimsIdentity?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.GivenName);

            return claim?.Value ?? string.Empty;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the value of the custom user property LastName
        /// </summary>
        /// <example>
        /// User.Identity.GetLastName()
        /// </example>
        /// <param name="identity">Usually the Identity of the current logged in User</param>
        /// <returns><see langword="string"/> containing value of LastName or an empty string</returns>
        public static string GetLastName(this IIdentity identity)
        {
            ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            Claim claim = claimsIdentity?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Surname);

            return claim?.Value ?? string.Empty;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the value of the custom user property OrgCode
        /// </summary>
        /// <example>
        /// User.Identity.GetOrgCode()
        /// </example>
        /// <param name="identity">Usually the Identity of the current logged in User</param>
        /// <returns><see langword="string"/> containing value of OrgCode or an empty string</returns>
        public static string GetOrgCode(this IIdentity identity)
        {
            ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            Claim claim = claimsIdentity?.FindFirst(CustomClaimTypes.OrgCode);

            return claim?.Value ?? string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

---

I am setting up a new site and want to modify `_LoginPartial.cshtml`.  I want to replace the display of the logged in username(an email address) with the logged in FirstName

```
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a id="manage" class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!</a> 
    </li>
   ...
}
```

to this

```
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a id="manage" class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @User.Identity.GetFirstName()!</a> 
    </li>
   ...
}
```

however, this results in empty text.  **Why is this blank?**

Clicking through into the `Account/Manage/Index` page I am presented with a form for modifying user details.  I have modified the InputModel to include two of the custom properties (FirstName, LastName).  The `LoadAsync` task has been modified to load values (using the extension methods) and add them to an `InputModel

```
private async Task LoadAsync(ApplicationUser user)
{

    var userName = await _userManager.GetUserNameAsync(user);
    var phoneNumber = await _userManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(user);
    var firstName =  user.FirstName;
    var lastName = user.LastName;
    var orgCode = user.OrgCode;


    Username = userName;

    OrgCode = orgCode;

    Input = new InputModel
    {
        PhoneNumber = phoneNumber,
        FirstName = firstName,
        LastName = lastName

    };
}
```

[image: Screenshot of User Modify page]

**Why are the custom properties visible on this page, but not on the previous?**

Further in `Account/Manage/Index` is the update method `OnPostAsync()`

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
   var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
   if (user == null)
   {
       return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
   }

   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       await LoadAsync(user);
       return Page();
   }

   var phoneNumber = await _userManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(user);
   if (Input.PhoneNumber != phoneNumber)
   {
       var setPhoneResult = await _userManager.SetPhoneNumberAsync(user, Input.PhoneNumber);
       if (!setPhoneResult.Succeeded)
       {
           var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
           throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unexpected error occurred setting phone number for user with ID '{userId}'.");
       }
   }

   var firstName = user.FirstName; //.GetPhoneNumberAsync(user);
   if (Input.FirstName != firstName)
   {
       //var setFirstNameResult = await _userManager.SetFirstNameAsync(user, Input.FirstName);
       user.FirstName = Input.FirstName;
       //if (!setFirstNameResult.Succeeded)
       //{
       //    var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
       //    throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unexpected error occurred setting First Name for user with ID '{userId}'.");
       //}
   }


   var lastName = user.LastName;
   if (Input.LastName != lastName)
   {
       //var setLastNameResult = await _userManager.SetLastNameAsync(user, Input.LastName);
       user.LastName = Input.LastName;
       //if (!setLastNameResult.Succeeded)
       //{
       //    var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
       //    throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unexpected error occurred setting Last Name for user with ID '{userId}'.");
       //}
   }

   await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);
   StatusMessage = "Your profile has been updated";
   return RedirectToPage();
}
```

Without Set methods like `SetPhoneNumberAsync()` I tried using the property setter.  This didn't work.  **How do I update Identity User Custom Property values?**

I just want to be able to use custom User properties.  I need the FirstName & OrgCode property available as soon as they log in, which isn't currently the case.  The current extension methods don't always work.

In addition, I need to be able to edit these properties in case their are errors or changed requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create scope of identity, just create your identity and add scoped

```
services.AddScoped<IUserIdentity, UserIdentity>();
```

You need to implement `middleware` for map all your properties in identity.
Add to startup:

```
app.UseMiddleware<UserIdentityAccessor>();
```

Implementation:

```
    public class UserIdentityAccessor
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public UserIdentityAccessor(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, IUserIdentity userIdentity)
        {
            var user = (ClaimsIdentity) context.User.Identity;

            if (user.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var first = user.FindFirst(ClaimsName.FirstName).Value; \\ get info from claims
                userIdentity.FirstName = first;                         \\ and add to identity
            }
            else
            {
                userIdentity.FirstName = null;
            }

            await _next(context);
        }
    }
```

And now you can get identity wherever you want

Comment: Should UserIdentity become ApplicationUserIdentity,to match my implementation?

Comment: `services.AddScoped<IUserIdentity, UserIdentity>();` added to Startup.ConfigureServices().  IUserIdentity, UserIdentity do not resolve.  Missing include?

`app.UseMiddleware<UserIdentityAccessor>();` added to Startup.Configure()

`UserIdentityAccessor` created in FleetLogix.Intranet.Identity namespace. IUserIdentity nlot resolving here either.  
had to change `ClaimsName.FirstName` to `ClaimTypes.GivenName`

Comment: Your answer dredged up memories of having done this before.  Along with https://adrientorris.github.io/aspnet-core/identity/extend-user-model.html I also found CustomClaimsPrincipalFactory.cs in an old project. Registering that as `services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, CustomClaimsPrincipalFactory>();` in ConfigureServices seems to have solved my issue, but accepting yours as it lead me to the correct answer.

Comment: Sorry for my incomplete answer, User identity its your not inherited class, I dont use inbuilt Identity when i wanna add some custom features

Comment: UserIdentity in my example is just class with cuple properties. Also what Authentication token do you use, JWT?

Comment: Hello, yes, i use jwt